# Proper Interface (Implements) syntax for class method with signature (Of T As Class)() As T

Tags: vb.net, interface

I have a hard time to either figure out the correct interface or actual implementation signature/syntax for a method. The method itself works as expected, the compiler at least doesn't complain about the interface's syntax, but when actually adding the necessary Implements statement to the method, it fails.

Here's what I have:

```
Public Interface IMyInterface
   Function GetIt(Of T As Class)() As T
End Interface

Public Class Foo
   Implements IMyInterFace

   Public Function GetIt(Of T As Class)() As T
End Class
```

If I now try to add the necessary Implements statement, even using autocompletion from the IntelliSense popup, VS complains about the syntax. Without the Implements statement, VS complains:

> BC30149   Class 'Foo' must implement 'Function GetIt(Of T As
>   Class)() As T' for interface 'IMyInterface'.

First, doing so by using autocompletion ends up with the following incomplete line:

```
Public Function GetIt(Of T As Class)() As T Implements IMyInterface.GetIt(Of
```

VS obviously complains about a)

> 'Type expected'

and b)

> ')' expected

Second, upon completing that line with

```
Public Function GetIt(Of T As Class)() As T Implements IMyInterface.GetIt(T As class) As T
```

VS still reports

> ')' expected

and points to the 'A' in the parameter definition 'As Class'.

So what's the right syntax for this kind of method signature?

Comment: My autocomplete does this: Public Function GetIt(Of T As Class)() As T Implements IMyInterface.GetIt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[MyClass is a keyword](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2849394/832052), so you can't name the class that.

You can close keywords in square brackets in VB.NET to avoid that.

```
Public Interface IMyInterface
    Function GetIt(Of T As Class)() As T
End Interface

Public Class [MyClass]
    Implements IMyInterface

    Public Function GetIt(Of T As Class)() As T Implements IMyInterface.GetIt
        Throw New NotImplementedException()
    End Function
End Class
```

But since this is just a proof of concept, your actual implementation probably won't suffer from this issue.

By the way, I'm voting to close your question because it's more of a question about using `MyClass` as a class name. If you hadn't done that your auto-complete surely would have generated the proper method signature. Instead your IDE was getting confused by the misplaced keyword. I hope this helped you solve your problem

Comment: My bad. I used "MyClass" just in this sample code, not keeping in mind it's a keyword. The actual class has a different name. I've updated my post to avoid that confusion.

Answer (score 1):

You're both correct, the solution is

```
Public Function GetIt(Of T As Class)() As T Implements IMyInterface.GetIt
```

I also had the idea of letting VS do the refactoring (*Edit -> Refactor -> Extract Interface*) and the above is what VS did that way. I still find it strange that VS (2017)'s autocompletion yields a different result.